# Understand abelian group theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group

I don't understand this statement from Wikipedia page:  "Every abelian group of order 8 is isomorphic to either $ \Bbb Z_8\ $ (the integers 0 to 7 under addition modulo 8), $ \Bbb Z_4\ \oplus \Bbb Z_2\ $  (the odd integers 1 to 15 under multiplication modulo 16), or $ \Bbb Z_2\ \oplus \Bbb Z_2\ \oplus \Bbb Z_2\ $ ."

Isn't $ \Bbb Z_4\ $ the integers 0 to 3 under addition modulo 4 i.e. {0,1,2,3} ? What did I misunderstand?

I thought that $ \Bbb Z_4\ \oplus \Bbb Z_2\ $ should be {0,1,2,3}$\oplus${0,1} but obviously there is some misunderstanding from me, especially since it also says that The cyclic group $\Bbb {Z} _{mn}$ of order mn is isomorphic to the direct sum of ${\Bbb Z} _{m}$ and ${\Bbb Z} _{n}$ and then uses as an example $\Bbb Z_{15} \cong \{0,5,10\} \oplus \{0,3,6,9,12\}$ but {0,5,10} is not ${\Bbb Z} _{3}$, it is just order 3.

Please explain...

Comment: $\Bbb Z_4\oplus \Bbb Z_2$ is **isomorphic** to $\Bbb Z_{16}^\times$. It is but very suboptimal to give the spelled out description of the latter as a definition-like description of the former, in particular in a beginner's context.

Answer (score 0):

You are right to the extent that $\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_2$ is indeed (by definition!) the cartesian product of the additive groups of integers modulo $4$ and modulo $2$.

What the Wiki page is suggesting is that you can find a "concrete" incarnation of this group by looking at the *multiplicative* group $U_{16}$ of the invertible elements in $\Bbb Z_{16}$ which has clearly $8$ elements (represented by the odd natural numbers from $1$ up to $15$) and it is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_2$.

For, consider that $U_{16}$ has elements of exact order $4$ (e.g. $\bar 3$) and $3$ elements of exact order $2$, namely $\bar 7$, $\bar 9$ and $\overline{15}$. I'll leave to you the task to write down an explicit isomorphism between $U_{16}$ and $\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: but why is the order 8 from Z_4 × Z_2 ? Z_4 × Z_2 would be {0,1,2,3} × {0,1} and I must have misunderstood some basic part because that is not 8 elements for me.

Comment: @Niklas: by definition, if $S$ and $T$ are sets, the cartesian product $S\times T$ is the set of all **pairs** $(s,t)$ with $s\in S$ and $t\in T$. If there are $m$ elements in $S$ and $n$ elements in $T$ the number of pairs as above is $m\cdot n$ (arrange all pairs in a rectangular array and count). Moreover, if $S$ and $T$ are groups, then $S\times T$ is a group under the operation $(s,t)\cdot(s',t')=(ss',tt')$.

Comment: @Niklas Post Scriptum: for the pupose of understanding Wiki's page, the notations $S\bigoplus T$ and $S\times T$ have the same meaning.

Comment: $ \Bbb Z_4\ \oplus \Bbb Z_2\ $ = (0,1,2,3) $ \oplus\ $ (0,1) = ((0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(2,0),(2,1),(3,0),(3,1)) which is 8 elements then. That much I can understand. It still beats me why that would be isomorphic to the odd numbers from 1 up to 15 under multiplication but I will try and go through it again.

Comment: @Niklas: I gave you a hint showing the existence of an element of order $4$ and of $3$ elements of exact order $2$. Note that $\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_2$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$ (there you have your three elements of exact order $2$).

Comment: I don't know what "exact order" means and it is the first time I see something like $\bar 9$, I don't know what that means and Wiki and Google does not answer it.

Comment: @Niklas: an element $g$ in a group $G$ has exect order $k(>0)$ if $g^k=1_G$ and $g^n\neq1_G$ for all $0<n<k$. Concerning your second question, do you know what $\Bbb Z_N$ is? And if you do, how you denote the class of $n\in\Bbb Z$ in $\Bbb Z_N$?

Comment: Please have a look at my follow-up question, I am beginning to understand some of it https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3638454